# MySQL Doesn't accept some data types

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench doesn't allow me to use BLOB() and DATETIME() data types. Im getting this error. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of BLOB() and DATETIME() use `BLOB` and `DATETIME` respectively

Comment: The parentheses are there for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your data types are incomplete. BLOB and DATETIME (as well as a few other types) allow to specify precisions within parentheses. MySQL Workbench adds empty ones for you, but you have to fill them with a good value. Alternatively, you can just remove them to use the default precision.